# Android Navigation Bar has half transparant square behind it when making background color transparant

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar

I have a project for which I'm doing a transparant bottom nav bar, only the icons are visible.

I've taken the default Bottom Navigation Activity project from Android Studio and made the background of the Nav Bar transparant:

```
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Now there is a half transparant square with 8dp padding left and right going through the icons (and top padding appears 16dp?)... On Nexus 5X the image seems skewed? Any ideas how to remove this?

Galaxy S7:
[image]

Nexus 5X:
[image]

Here is the full xml code for reference:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this on my Pixel Android 10, so just a random guess: Have you tried setting `app:elevation="0dp"`?

Comment: This solves the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that adding the following attribute to the `<BottomNavigationView />` inside the XML fixes the problem:

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

(Just putting the answer from the comments into a regular answer)